# db2 datetime conversion to date issue

Tags: db2

I have date column in following format: 
20120714042548334 
20120714042548334  
20120714042549375

Trying to query the table for a certain range, I am getting an error that says "The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007", error outs right away or after few thousand records are displayed. 
Query I am using is

```
select * from AUDIT
where date(substr(serv_start_date_time,1,4)||'-' ||substr(serv_start_date_time,5,2) ||'-'||
substr(serv_start_date_time,7,2)) between date('9/4/2012') and date('9/10/2012')
```

Any help or assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: At a guess, it's complaining because you're using mm/dd/yyyy formats in the `date()` function.  Please always use `*ISO`, for internationalization and future maintenance safety.  Also, please avoid the use of `BETWEEN` when dealing with ranges, especially for 'variable precision types' (essentially, anything other than an integer count) - [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) lists why for date/time/timestamp types (and SQL Server in particular, but it applies to all RDBMSs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting your range dates in ISO format:

```
select * from AUDIT
where date( substr(serv_start_date_time,1,4) ||'-'
          ||substr(serv_start_date_time,5,2) ||'-'
          ||substr(serv_start_date_time,7,2)
          ) between date('2012-09-04') and date('2012-09-10')
```

Or faster, by avoiding type conversions, stick to character comparison since it seems that's what your data column is to begin with.

```
select * from AUDIT
where serv_start_date_time between '20120904' and '20120910'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

If you can provide more details as to how you're accessing it that would help.
I access SQL via ruby - different situation, but knowing what tools you have at your disposal would help.

If you can use regular expressions at all,
/([\d]{4})([\d]{2})([\d]{2})[\d]{9}/ will return:
2012 07 04
for
20120714042548334

Query suggestion:

Also, If the column is Date,
Something to the effect of

```
SELECT Date FROM AUDIT WHERE Date>=20120714000000000 AND Date<20120824000000000
```

Should pull out everything between July 14 and August 23, for example.

In your 9/4 to 9/10, it'd be:

```
SELECT Date FROM AUDIT WHERE Date>=20120904000000000 AND Date<20120911000000000
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: SQL, toad for Oracle. Do you know any way to format the date in db2 to mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Regex is not available on all DB2 platforms, and it would be far more efficient to do the record selection on the server than to fetch all the records into Ruby (or some other language) in order to perform your selection that way.

Comment: I didn't think it(regex) was, and obviously fetching all the records would be ridiculous. I was also thinking formatting selected records can be done quick anywhere if there's never more than a few dozen of them. Excellent answer btw.